# add UTF-8 charset to to response headers in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot application which sends and receives data in various forms such as application/json , application/xml , application/x-www-form-urlencoded , ... .

I want to write a custom filter to set UTF-8 charset to response headers. But I want to apply this only to the responses where the contentType header is set to "application/json" .

How Can I achieve this goal ?

I tried to add the following to application.yml :

```
server:
  servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      force-response: true
```

But I doubt that it will apply to all responses(not just "application/json" ones).

Another thing I have done so far is writing a filter :

```
public class CharEncodingFilter extends CharacterEncodingFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        filterChain.doFilter(request , response);

        if (response.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) {
            String encoding = getEncoding();
            if (encoding != null) {
                if (isForceRequestEncoding() || request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
                    request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
                }
                if (isForceResponseEncoding()) {
                    response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

but it fails to fulfill my request, because `response.getContentType()` is null and the if-statement will produce nullPointerException :( .

I know somewhere in the application, the contentType is set for the responses by springboot, and I want to add UTF-8 encoding charset header right after that.

P.S: I want a global solution. I know it's applicable to set the response type of each of the controller methods seperately, but it's time consuming to fix all controllers.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You’re on the right track with creating a custom filter. However, the issue you’re facing is that the content type of the response is not set until after the controller method is executed. Therefore, when your filter is checking the content type, it’s still null.

To solve this, you can create a wrapper for the `HttpServletResponse` and override the `setContentType` method. In this method, you can check if the content type being set is “`application/json`” and if so, add the charset to the response headers.

Here’s an example of how you can do it:

```
public class CharEncodingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
            @Override
            public void setContentType(String type) {
                if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.equals(type)) {
                    super.setContentType(type + ";charset=UTF-8");
                } else {
                    super.setContentType(type);
                }
            }
        };
        filterChain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
    }
}
```

In this code, `OncePerRequestFilter` is a type of filter provided by Spring that ensures the filter is only applied once per request. When the `setContentType` method is called on the responseWrapper, it checks if the type is “`application/json`”. If it is, it sets the content type with the UTF-8 charset. Otherwise, it sets the content type as usual.

Remember to register this filter in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CharEncodingFilter> charEncodingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CharEncodingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CharEncodingFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```